# Subscribed Calendar name has the .ics URL when opened from a UIWebView

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, icalendar, vcalendar

My iPhone app (supporting iOS 6+) has a web view which lists events with a "Add To Calendar" button for each event. The "Add To Calendar" button is a hyperlink to an .ics file on the server. To make this work, I have modified IIS to use "text/calendar" as the MIME type for .ics files and used the following code in my UIWebView delegate's shouldStartLoadWithRequest: when the request URL contains the ".ics" path extension

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:ics_url];

When tapping on the "Add To Calendar" button for an event, I get an alert "Subscribe to the calendar "http://blah.com/pathtoics/file.ics"" with 2 buttons Subscribe and Cancel. When I tap "Subscribe", I get another alert "The Calendar "http://blah.com/pathtoics/file.ics" has been added" with 2 buttons "View Events" and "Done". When I open the Calendar app by tapping on "View Events" button, I see the event gets added but the Subscribed Calendar name is the URL "http://blah.com/pathtoics/file.ics"

Two Questions:

Is there a way to modify the alert to say "Subscribe to the calendar event Team Event 1"" i.e., the event name/description instead of the server path to the ics file? If so, how do I do that?

Is there a way to make the name of the Subscribed Calendar to be a description text that I use in the ics file instead of the path to the ics file? If so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the ICS file, make sure `X-WR-CALNAME` is set to the calendar name you wish to be displayed in the alert and as the name of the subscribed calendar.

Comment: Thanks. That worked. I have a different issue now, will post another question.